# Outlook AddIn - Spell check show up twice on send event

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The [spellcheck box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KOuA.png) shows twice, once when clicked on the send button and another time after the Outlook AddIn gets resolved. (After the event.completed)

It is a Windows platform using Outlook 365 app.

manifest.xml

```xml
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>

<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
</Rule>

<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://some.url/index.html" ></bt:Url>
      </bt:Urls>
    </Resources>
```

app.js

```js
function validateBody(event) {
    Office.onReady().then(function() {
        var contextInfo = Office.context.diagnostics;
        if(contextInfo.platform == 'OfficeOnline'){
            //Do something
        } else{
            event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you help us with more details about your issue such as Platform (Web, Win32, Mac etc.), a code snippet/link to add-in's manifest, video/screenshots so we can better understand your use case and question.

Comment: What code do you have in the onsend event handler?

Comment: It just check if it is a web or application, if it is not web, it just allow the event.

I dont see this problem on the browser or in the mac, just windows outlook app

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 

Basically, the add-in captures the email that will be sent, check the platform and if the platform is not web, it release (allow) the email.

On windows 365 and 2021 app, the spellcheck box show ups twice, once after the user press send, but before the add-in loads and another after the add-in release the message. 

I edit the post with the manifest and the app.js

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side with the latest Outlook build. Could you specify the exact version you have installed on your side?